# Is it possible to use the web audio api with deezer javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, deezer

I am currently building a small app where music visualization happens. Currently I have to embed my mp3's or have to search for them on soundcloud.

The spotify API does not allow you to access the song in a web app and everything happens via the widget.

Is Deezer (and all other music streaming services for that matter) in the same boat? I can't quite figure out from the javascript SDK page if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it is not possible to retrieve the MP3s directly, you have to use the Javascript SDK that does not allow to have a music visualization unfortunately.